# Structuring a LSTM Layer

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, bert

I'm trying to improve an NER Bert sequence tagger using LSTM layers in TensorFlow. I'm a bit unclear on the interface and how a LSTM layer should be set up.

Currently, I'm taking in 3-5 sentences and outputting a layer of shape 
`(?, 5, max_token_length,token_vector_output)`.
I'd like to take into consideration previous sentence output for the next sequence I'm tagging.

Reshaping the above to `(?, 5, max_token_length*token_vector_output)` we can then apply a tf.keras.layers.LSTM layer, but this will yield a tensor of shape `(?, unit_size)` This appears to kill all sequence data off. Is this the correct way to feed my data to a LSTM layer?

**As an update, I think I have found a solution - let me know if this isn't a correct way to structure the network.**

The LSTM will output a tensor `(?, unit_size)` regularly - but this is the current state of the LSTM layer. Using the `return_sequences=True` argument, it will instead return a tensor of shape `(?,sequence_length, unit_size)`, which is the history of the internal states.

In my case, I will be structuring the input as `(?, 5 * max_token_length, token_vector_output)` to the LSTM layer, returning a `(?, 5 * max_token_length, unit_size)` tensor. Taking the last `max_token_length` on axis 1, I'll get the states during the sentence I'm tagging. My logits will a weighted sum of this state tensor and the regular sequential Bert Output of that sentence, and applying a softmax will give the final labels!